# Show confirmation dialog and get the answer inside the same Button's click callback

Tags: kotlin, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

Currently, when I want to show a confirmation dialog I do this by controlling its visiblity with such variables as `confirmationDialogVisible` and wiring the actual API to the `confirmButton` callback of the `AlertDialog`.

I find this approach pretty inconvenient as you quickly lose track of what is called where and under which conditions. In this example here there's only one dialog, but if more were required this would quickly become a mess.

So, I was wonderting whether there's a way in Jetpack Compose to show a dialog and get the answer within the same `Button`'s `onClick` callback like underneath the `// pseudocode` comment?

```kotlin
class Model {
    fun delete() {
        // performs deletion
        println("Delete!")
    }
}

@Composable
fun Demo() {
    val model = remember { Model() }
    var confirmationDialogVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Button(
        onClick = {
            // doesn't call the delete API, but shows a dialog
            confirmationDialogVisible = true
            
            // psedudocode
            if(showConfirmationDialog()) { // <-- How can I achieve this?
                model.delete()
            }
        }
    ) { Text("Delete") }

    if (confirmationDialogVisible) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { confirmationDialogVisible = false },
            confirmButton = {
                // dialog calls the delete API
                model.delete()
            },
            dismissButton = { confirmationDialogVisible = false }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution You can pass the value of your Model when you make AlertDialog visible to the user.

And when user Click on Yes it will return the id of that record or complete object and then you can perform the task.

**Example**
I have made a sample **ViewModel** for easy understanding and data class which you can customize as your choice.

`ViewModel` with a simple delete method which will receive id and proceed to delete record from the database or API.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun delete(id: Int) {
        println("Delete Record $id")
    }
}
```

Sample Data Class You Can Change As Per Your Wish

```
data class MyData(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

Here is a complete example.

```
@Composable
fun Stack014() {

    val viewModel = viewModel<MyViewModel>()

    val clearAllMessageDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    if (clearAllMessageDialog.value) {
        openDialog(
            myData = MyData(1, "Name"),
            onConfirm = { id ->
                clearAllMessageDialog.value = false
                viewModel.delete(id)
            }) {
            clearAllMessageDialog.value = false
        }
    }

    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(onClick = { clearAllMessageDialog.value = true }) {
            Text(text = "Open Dialog")
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun openDialog(
    myData: MyData,
    onConfirm: (Int) -> Unit,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
) {

    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            onDismiss()
        },
        title = {
            Text(
                text = "Delete Record",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 16.sp
            )
        },
        text = {
            Text(
                "Do you want to delete record?",
                fontSize = 16.sp
            )
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    onConfirm(myData.id)
                }) {
                Text("Yes", style = TextStyle(color = Color.Black))
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    onDismiss()
                }) {
                Text("No", style = TextStyle(color = Color.Black))
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Happy Compose.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but this brings me on a new idea...

Comment: I've managed to create a nice solution ;-] I'll post it on Code Review later and I'll let you know the link it you're curious.

Comment: [Here's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288806/dialog-manager-for-compose-dialogs) the code of my dialog-manager.